# SQL querying to calculate period of works and load data in another table

Tags: sql, ssis

i have a table in SQL Server called PointingSystem (screenshot below) that contains the pointing of all employees daily. I need to calculate the Period of work for each Employee according this formula :
sum (Output - Input) : it does mean (Output 1 - Input1) + (Output 2 - Input 2) + ....+(Output 2 - Input 2)

and according to these calculations , we load data into PeriodWorks table to summarize the period of work for all days in the month for each employee (Screenshot below).

I need your help for the necessary SQL requests to make these aggregation ( it's no problem for me the SSIS package after for loading data)

If you need a csv file that contains a sample data , contact me in private.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSURo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIYlI.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  SO is not a personal coding service.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT '

DECLARE @output nvarchar(max)

SELECT
    @output = COALESCE(@output + '+', N'') + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PointingSystem' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%output%'

SET @sql = @sql + @output + ' AS ''Output'', '


DECLARE @input nvarchar(max)

SELECT
    @input = COALESCE(@input + '+', N'') + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PointingSystem' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%input%'

SET @sql = @sql + @input + ' AS ''Input'''

SET @sql = @sql + ',(' + @output + ')-(' + @input  +') as Period FROM PointingSystem'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
SELECT ID_EMP, SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, DATE_IN, DATE_OUT))
FROM PointingSystem
GROUP BY ID_EMP
```